# django-storages/boto/s3 caching issue

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, celery, boto, django-storage

I run Django + Celery on Heroku.
I create files at a Celery task at background (Heroku worker) and I upload images to S3 using this method:

```
def uploadToS3(img, out):    
    out_im  = cStringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(out_im, 'gif') 
    conn = boto.connect_s3()   
    b = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')   
    k = b.new_key(out)   
    k.set_contents_from_string(out_im.getvalue(),{'Content-Type': 'image/gif'})
    k.set_acl('public-read')
    #test
    imageExists = default_storage.exists(out)

    if imageExists:
        print out +  " exists." 
    else:
        print out +  " does not exists."
```

It works perfectly. The image is indeed created.

The issue is that after the file is created and also visible at S3 web console and through a browser(it is there...) - running the same test:

```
    imageExists = default_storage.exists(my_image_path_at_s3)
```

at the other process (Django app) - returns false.

Only restarting the Django app caused it recognize the new file at s3.

It seems like caching, but I didn't managed to find where it is...

Any hints?